# why page show 404 when manually refreshing URL in browser angular 7 on JBOSS server?

Tags: angular, jboss

When I execute my application in browser it works perfectly as expected but when I press `F5 or refresh page` then it shows me `404 server error`.

I am searching for a long time for this issue and I find lots of answers but none of them worked for me.

I have implemented `HashLocationStrategy`. Here is below code:

> App.module.ts

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

and

```
imports: [
NgbModule.forRoot()],
providers:[{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

> Routing.module.ts (Create separated file for Routing)

```
@NgModule({
imports:[
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
],
exports:[RouterModule]
})
```

Note 1 : Instead of marking "Negative" I request you to please ask me anything if you need more clarification.

Note 2 : I am new to this and I don't have knowledge of server side or JAVA language

Comment: Can you add the URL you are trying to refresh?

Comment: https://10.32.18.226:8445/commonprov/WebClientV2/#/message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution of my Question.

Below code I added in **web.xml** file only and works for me.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/WebClientV2/index.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/login</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/messages</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/contacts</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/staff-assignment</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/nurse-rounding</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WebClientV2/myPatient</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **web.config** file in server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I do not have web.config file on server. I have web.xml file which contains all URL mapping of existing application which is made in Java/Struts

Comment: The given configuration is is xml only. Try adding it in your own file

Comment: below is web.xml code and i want to know Is there any option to give direct link of `index.html` file instead `<server-class>` or any other way. 

`<servlet>
<servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/commonprov/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Well I have no idea about `<server-class>`

Comment: No worries...anyways I got my solution. Please see my latest comment below(if Interested). Thanks for your help!